# fitting two dimensional curves in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

There's a toolbox function for the curve fitting toolbox called cftool that lets you fit curves to 1-d data. Is there anything for 2-d data?

Answer (score 7):

Jerry suggested two very good choices. There are other options though, if you want a more formulaic form for the model.

The curvefitting toolbox, in the current version, allows you to fit surfaces to data, not just curves.

Or fit a 2-d polynomial model, using a tool like [polyfitn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10065).

Or you can use a nonlinear regression, if you have a model in mind. The optimization toolbox will help you there, with lsqnonlin or lsqcurvefit, either of which can fit 2-d (or higher) models. Or, if you have the stats toolbox, then try nlinfit.

Perhaps you might like a tool to fit [Radial Basis Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10056-scattered-data-interpolation-and-approximation-using-radial-base-functions).

Neural nets are another way to fit data, so use the [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neuralnet/)

So there are many ways to model surfaces, depending on your interests, your knowledge of a likely form for the model, what toolboxes you have or what you might choose to download. A very big factor in your model choice are your goals for the model. What will you do with it? How will it be used?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for [griddata](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/griddata.html). You might also want to look at [gridfit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit).