# 2d polynomial fitting to table data MATLAB

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, data-fitting

I am trying to use 2D polynomial fitting for my table data, my data format is exactly like the link below:
http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/curvefit/brx2ldg-1.html#bso46rp-1

I mean I have vector `X` with length `n`, `Y` with length `m` and `m*n` Matrix `Z`, I would like to fit 5 degree 2d polynomial to my data,

I am wondering that is there any syntax in MATLAB for solving this problem? like SFIT command in IDL, http://star.pst.qub.ac.uk/idl/SFIT.html

I have `cftool` and `sftool`, but it seems that they don't work for this purpose or most probably I don't know how to employ them.

and I know that there some m.file which people share in MATLAB Mathworks file exchange, please if you know one works properly, suggest me.

I'd appreciate any help and comment.

Comment: I am also trying to employ Sfit in IDl, but I couldn't find hot to use it, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe the answers here are of additional help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963874/fitting-two-dimensional-curves-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [polyfitn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) from file exchange and re-format your data in order to have 3 `MxN` `x,y,z` vectors.

**Example**:

Assume you have a table data of the form

```
N = 100; M = 80;
x = linspace(0, 1, M);
y = linspace(0, 1, N).';
z = bsxfun(@franke, x, y);
```

Create `meshgrid` for x, and y instead

```
N = 100; M = 80;
[x, y] = meshgrid(0:1:N, 0:1:M);
z = bsxfun(@franke, x, y);
```

(Note that `unique(x)` and `unique(y)` will give you the original `linspace` values of your table rows and columns.)

Use [polyfitn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) to get the 5-degree polynomial coefficients

```
p = polyfitn([x(:),y(:)], z(:), 5);
```

You can additionally convert the result into a symbolic form to view the polynomial using the provided `polyn2sym(p)`

```
>> pretty(polyn2sym(p))

                      5                           4                             4                         3   2
     90264379051097 X1         2537627280433653 X1  X2       7778045812403061 X1       6982058230382053 X1  X2
- ------------------------- - -------------------------- + ------------------------ - -------------------------- + ...
  2417851639229258349412352   38685626227668133590597632   604462909807314587353088   77371252455336267181195264
```

Comment: but I have x, y vectors, and z as a martix

Comment: yes, in my answer I assume you have that (lines 1-4 of code) and suggest how you can get to a convenient all-matrix representation from it (lines 5-7). In essence create a `meshgrid` from your x,y vectors and leave matrix z intact. `polyfitn` then can be applied as shown.

Comment: I face with this error; which I don't know why, I put my data to my question. could you plz help me?                                   ??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: the only place you could be getting that error is in `[x(:),y(:)]` inside `polyfitn`. Remember, x, y are originally vectors, which you turn into matrices, by `meshgrid`. Then, irrespective of their original length, doing `[x(:),y(:)]`, i.e. concatenating the vector-turned matrices, will work.